# Create a new column with unique by concatenation of 3 column

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, unique

I want to create below final concate_col by concatenation of **col1**, **col2** and **col3** in python

```
Col1 col2 col3 concate_col
a     b    b      a,b
c     a    a      c,a
d     a    e      d,a,e
```

I am able to concatenate these 3 column but is having in getting unique values in each rows.

I have used df.str.cat to concatenate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd


data = {'col1': ['a', 'c', 'd'],
        'col2': ['b', 'a', 'a'],
        'col3': ['b', 'a', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Concatenate unique values of col1, col2, and col3 for each row
df['concate_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join(set(row)), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  col1 col2 col3 concate_col
0    a    b    b         b,a
1    c    a    a         c,a
2    d    a    e       d,e,a
```

Comment: Thanks Taras. Its very useful. I can apply this logic to small set and its working              
 import pandas as pd


data = {'test1': ['x', 'y', 'y'],
        'test2': ['x', 'a', 'b'],
        'col1': ['a', 'c', 'd'],
        'col2': ['b', 'a', 'a'],
        'col3': ['b', 'a', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Concatenate unique values of col1, col2, and col3 for each row
df['concate_col'] = df[[c for c in df.columns if 'col' in c]].apply(lambda row: ','.join(set(row)), axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['concate_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If order is important, use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.apply.html) :

```
df["concate_col"] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ",".join(pd.unique(x)))
```

Another variant with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) :

```
df["concate_col"] = df.agg(lambda x: ",".join(pd.unique(x)), axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  col1 col2 col3 concate_col
0    a    b    b         a,b
1    c    a    a         c,a
2    d    a    e       d,a,e
```